# I am trying to encrypt Primary key using AES encrypt method in django

Tags: python, url, encryption, primary-key, django-urls

For Example:

URL as follows : http://www.example.com/3/test/

and in response it is giving me the encrypted primary key in URL as follows http://www.example.com/yL9emMXPt7Uiq+EecpIbkk7WoIyKlbM3vXDKXsHY=/test/ ,but it is showing page not found (404) error.

So i need some guidance on how to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: Please add snippet of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

What did you used to encrypt the URL ?
If that was **Python**'s **base64** module, then please add it in **Flask/Django**'s route.

Comment: No that's not base64 module, i have used custom function from util.py file to encyrpt the url.

Comment: What do you use to create the Web Page.